# Online database of ETF & Mutual Fund Fees?

Tags: data, etf, mutual-fund, fees

Is there any online data source of ETF and/or mutual fund fees? Free or paid is fine, although hopefully there's something out there cheaper than Bloomberg

Comment: You mean historical fees(delisted and fee changes)? or just current fees?

Comment: Just current would be good enough to start

Answer (score 1):

MorningStar or Lipper will be your best bets if you want everything in a nice machine readable format. [factset/etf.com](http://www.etf.com/etfanalytics/etfcom-data-products) or [etfdb](http://etfdb.com/data-and-licensing-opportunities/) are great sources for etf data.

If you want to go through the web, you can try etf.com or etfdb.com for the ETFs and morningstar.com for the mutual funds.